# Naming selector with string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a button programatically and i'm adding an action to the button like this:

```
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But I want to name the selector with a string with format.. I have tried like this:

```
[b4 addTarget:self action:@selector([NSString stringWithFormat@"button%i", i]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Of course this doesn't work, but are there something similar I can do to make this work? If you understand my problem..

Comment: Yeah, why would you want to do this?  Much added complexity for no good reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work:

```
NSString *selName = [NSString stringWithFormat@"button%i", i];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selName);

[button1 addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But I must ask why you wish to do this. Are you trying to handle several buttons? That can easily be done with a single selector for all buttons. Give each button its own tag. Then the button selector can check the sender's tag.

Comment: +1. I'd give it a +2 if I could for going the extra mile in pointing out the potential design pitfall.

Comment: @jlehr There are a lot of real world cases that dynamic methods at runtime fits better, and that's why most script languages support this feature. Whenever you want to use function pointer, string based methods calling makes things easy. This is actually an advantage of objc, not sure why you mock it.